# Plotting a polar equation with smooth appearance

Tags: java, graph, coordinate-systems

I am trying to plot a polar equation in Java. Naively plotting the individual points leads to a very lumpy result. I think this is because the anti-aliasing cannot work with a graph made up of very short line segments.

There is a well known algorithm for plotting smooth XY graphs. Essentially you approximate the function with line segments. Each line segment is then subdivided recursively until it fits the curve within some tolerance. This works very well.

I tried to adapt this for polar plots by calculating the XY coordinates and using the same algorithm, but it doesn't seem to work - I suspect it is because the points are not evenly distributed in x. The line segments are too visible, but decreasing the tolerance to fit more closely results in some other parts of the curve getting lumpy again.

Does anyone know an algorithm for plotting a polar equation smoothly?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "well known algorithm" for XY plots?

Comment: Maybe he is thinking of [De Casteljau's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm), which I don't think can be used here

Comment: Sorry I don't have a link, I don't remember where I saw it. Maybe it isn't well known, but it is fairly obvious. Start by calculating, eg, every 32nd pixel to make a crude approximation to the graph. If the line section is a good approximation leave it, if not calculate the mid point, and repeat until it fits well enough. You end up with a set of lines segments, probably of various lengths, which approximate the curve.